# Expand a relative path in Ant script, for Inkscape

Tags: ant, build-automation, filenames, inkscape

I'd like to write an Ant script that calls an external utility (Inkscape, in fact) that needs a full path. Right now I have

```
<exec executable="${inkscape.path}">
    <arg value="--file=build_exe/splash.svg" />
    <arg value="--export-png=build_exe/splash.png" />
    <arg value="-C" />
</exec>
```

On Windows, [Inkscape requires absolute paths](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#I.27m_on_Windows.2C_and_command_line_parameters_don.27t_seem_to_work.21). So how can I coax Ant to make `build_exe/filename` into an absolute path for me? Or, alternately, is there a workaround for Inkscape (maybe setting the working directory)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

```
<property name="x" location="folder/file.txt" />
```

the `${X}` value will be the absolute path of the file relative to the `${basedir}` value.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare

```
<property file="my_config.properties"/>
```

and I would write this path in the file my_config.properties. Your users will just have to modify this config file.